# Can I publish a "revised edition" of my book with a different publisher?

Tags: publishing, copyright, publisher, international

I published my book in 2013 with one publisher in India.  As I was unhappy with the publisher—he had made changes to the book while editing which I was not happy with—the book did not do very well.  I have now revised the book and want to publish, self publish.  Am I breaking the UK copyright law?

Comment: Is it fiction or nonfiction?  Nonfiction books are more likely to have "revised edition"s, but mostly fiction is done once it's out there, I thought.

Answer (score 4):

It really depends on what you signed in that original publishing contract.

Did you give them world rights? If so, you could end up in trouble.

As an independent, you should seriously consider joining the Alliance of Independent Authors or The Society of Authors. Both of which will review contracts and let you know where you stand.

Good luck!

Comment: NP... I hope you have your UK rights, since getting them back can be costly and time consuming. But ALLI and the SOA will help you. Good luck with your indie journey too. It's a lovely community. You should think about joining SPF Community and Indie Author Mindset on FB. Both of these groups are incredibly helpful.

Comment: @ShankarKashyap  Yeah, that's the answer: look at your contract.  Good luck!